# How can I access Class functions from outside of class, same .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, phaser-framework

I have a game with the **Phaser3** library. This game is in the file `phaser-game.component.ts`. The class within is meant to interact with other components and services. The functionality of the game is in this file, but **NOT** in the class. I need to access a specific method within the class, or the `scoreService` property of the class, from the `phaser-game.component.ts` file. How do I reference either.

1) a function within the class (`preferable`) from outside the class and within the same file or

2) the score (`typeof "ScoreService"`) of the class from outside the class and within the same file?

-referring to these properties as `"this.updateHighscore"`

-declaring a new `scoreService` outside of the class to access required function

-moving code to script tag inside `.html` document as opposed to the associated `.ts` file

```
Phaser-game.component.ts:
```

```
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';
import { ScoreService } from './../score.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Physics } from 'phaser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phaser-game',
  templateUrl: './phaser-game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phaser-game.component.css']
})
export class PhaserGameComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  user: any;

  constructor(private api: ApiService, private score: ScoreService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    game = new Phaser.Game(config);//Makes game
    console.log("Component loaded");//Debug
    this.api.getUser().subscribe(res => {//This works, gets user data
      res == {} ? (
        this.user = this.api.getUser().subscribe(res => {
          this.user = res;
        })
      ) : this.user = res;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("component being destroyed");
    game.destroy();
    moveSpeed = 200;
  }
  //This is the function that needs to be accessed
  updateHighscore(): void {
    this.score.updateHighscore(dataToSend);//This function works
 }
}
//End of class
/*
  Bunch of code relating to function of the game
*/
//This is the method that needs to do the update
//It's the games loop
update() {
  if (gameOver) {
  //Somehow get to the updateHighscore() method
  return; //This ends the game loop
  }
}
```

If any other code is required, let me know. As far as I've been able to test, everything works as intended, I just can't get to the `updateHighscore` in the class in this file. Thanks!

Expected results:

the **updateHighscore** function under **PhaserGameComponent** class successfully calls the **updateHighscore** function from the **scoreService** declared in its constructor.

Actual results:

everything I've tried can't access the **updateHighscore** function under **PhaserGameComponent** class. Typically `"X is undefined"`, 'x' being whatever I used to try and get to that function.

Comment: this will not work, typescript will be transpilled into javascript, the angular-cli will remove your game loop when it is building, I suggest to write a `GameLoopComponent` which uses the `PhaserGameComponent` then you can call `updateHighscore` method if you have a reference of the PhaserGameComponent instantiated

Comment: I will try that, thank you